# Exercise 2.3.2 in Huybrechts Complex geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $Y\subset X$ be a smooth hypersurface defined by a section $s\in H^0(X,L)$ for some holormorphic line bundle $L\in Pic(X)$.Show that the normal bundle $\mathcal N_{Y/X}$ is isomorphic to $L|_Y$.

I can prove this claim by using the cocycle description,however,how to prove it by using the fact "$\mathcal N_{Y/X}^*\cong\mathcal I_Y/\mathcal I_Y^2$".

Can anyone give me some advice?Thanks a lot!

Comment: A smooth hypersurface is locally cut out by a single non zerodivisor element $f$. Both bundles are locally defined by $f^{-1}O_{X}(U)/I(U)$ on a small open affine subset $U\cap Y$.

Comment: Dear @Ahr,thanks for your comment, can you explain it more concretely?"Both bundles are locally defined by ...".Many thanks.